# Is it possible to programmatically set the first 7 bits of $?

Tags: perl

When I implement a child process to handle signals, say `SIGTERM` and `SIGUSR1` using custom signal handlers which would exit the child process gracefully, is it possible to let the parent process know which signal causes the exit? `$?` has its first 7 bit set to indicate the signal the child process die from. However I am not sure how we can programmatically set it. A call to `exit()` would only set the value of `($? >> 8)`.

Comment: I want to say no, it's not possible, because of the layers of execution involved, but I don't think I could back up that assertion.

Answer (score 4):

My approach would be: In the signal handler, uninstall the custom signal handler and change the signal action to Terminate. Then in the main control flow, include logic that re-raises the same signal.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates the signal the killed the child, so the child would have to send itself a signal.

```
$ perl -E'system($^X, -e => q{kill TERM => $$}); say $?;'
15
```

If you have a handler for the signal, just unset it first.

```
$SIG{TERM} = 'DEFAULT';
```